# Se pueden agregar constantes como parametro a un require_once en php?

Tags: php, html, web

Buen día, estoy empezando en esto del PHP, tengo una duda, para agregar ficheros a un php es necesario hacer lo siguiente:

```
require_once '../rutafichero/fichero.php';
```

Mi pregunta es, suponiendo que en algún momento tenga que cambiar el nombre de la rutafichero o el mismo nombre del fichero y no quisiera estar actualizando todos lo PHP que incluyan ese fichero, hay alguna forma de poner una constante en lugar de la ruta? Por ejemplo hacer lo siguiente:

```
define('fichero','../rutafichero/fichero.php');
```

y después

```
require_once fichero;
```

lo intenté pero me marca error, por eso recurro a preguntar si hay alguna forma de hacer lo que intento.

De antemano muchas gracias a todos.

*PD: Trabajo con Windows y PHP 7.*

Answer (score 0):

No tendría que darte error.

```
define('c', '../../fend/controlador_.php');
require_once c;
```

es posible que el error este en otro lado, o ruta mal especificada.

en windows hay problemas con los slash.
`./../` podria ser igual a `.\\..\\..`

```
$slash = (substr(strtolower(php_uname('s')),0,3) == 'win') ? "\\" : "/";
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."{$slash}algo.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error, omití mencionar que las constantes se encontraban en otro archivo PHP, primer tuve que incluir el fichero y después llamar a la constante.